# How can I see the last date that a volume was used by docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volume, docker-volume, docker-container

I restarted elk because it crashed, but then my app crashed(all the containers) so I removed kibana, elastic and logstash and started the other ones again.

I have couple of old volumes that I did not deleted and I don't remember what was the name of the volume that I use in elk and I have couple of versions of elk compose file with the different volumes so I don't know which one was the latest one with all the data of the app.

So my idea is to see the date of the last modification of the volume so I can detect which one is the last volume that I used.

using:

```
docker inspect nameOfContainer
```

I can see "CreatedAt": "2020-03-04T16:31:54+01:00" but is there any way too see the latest modification date of the volume and not the creation date?

Comment: It would make more sence to find out when the volume was mounted last.

Answer (score 2):

How about checking the files inside the volume for the modification date?

```
docker run -it --rm -v <volume_name>:/volume busybox ls -alt /volume
```

Comment: ok not shure that this command will help me because i think that when i restart elk it maby count as the files was modified.

drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jan 28 13:18 ..
drwxrwxr-x    3 1000     root          4096 Feb 25  2020 .
drwxrwxr-x    3 1000     root          4096 Feb 25  2020 nodes